# JavaFx Layout Direction

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

How can I change layout direction of some container in JavaFX.
e.g. I use TreeTableView and want the columns to be directed from right to left (rtl), not the text inside the columns, the columns itself.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have never seen a tree oriented horizontally, can you think of an app/snapshot doing this ?

Comment: you mean the NodeOrientation?

Comment: Do you want to rotate the treeTableview by 90 degrees ?

Comment: No. I want to flip columns horizontally, and set alignment to the right instead of left.